# Which database invented the "limit" SQL query syntax?

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

MySQL has a nice feature (although non standard) which allow to query resultsets' limit, offset as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT M, N;
```

Is it created by MySQL? or Postgres?

Comment: The MySQL-syntax sucks, the first parameter has two different meanings: offset or limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between PostgreSQL and MySQL, PostgreSQL copied the syntax LIMIT from MySQL (in v6.5), and added the OFFSET syntax (it may be that that was copied as well, but I think mysql only had the comma-syntax back then). It was then (7.2) changed to *only* allow "LIMIT foo OFFSET bar" because the MySQL syntax was unclear.

Answer (score 13):

According to Wikipedia, [Rasmus Lerdorf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf) (the original creator of PHP) first used the "LIMIT x" syntax in the mSQL database:

> He has contributed to the Apache HTTP Server and **he also came up with the LIMIT clause** and added it to the [mSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSQL) Database in 1995. It is the origin of the LIMIT clauses found in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Limiting the result set is now also standardized, but with a more verbose syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: To be fair `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` just sucks compared to `LIMIT 10`.

Comment: Standard SQL sucks. I guess it's a tradition.

Comment: @Mark Byers - Clearly the people that built VB must consulting with the ISO people on SQL standards given how verbose that is.

Comment: @Thomas, Microsoft built VB and Microsoft's T-SQL is nice with TOP N. Someone else is behind this.

Comment: @Thomas - worse, I think it's the ANSI J4 COBOL committee <shudder!>

Comment: Such redundant syntax.  Why `FETCH`?  What else would you do with the results of a `SELECT`?  Why `ROWS`?  What else would you store in a table?  Why `ONLY`?  As if an SQL implementation would accept your limit clause and give you the full data set anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Postgres added the [LIMIT syntax in v6.5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.5/static/sql-select.htm), released on [June 9th, 1999](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/release-6-5.html).

[Based on the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html), MySQL had LIMIT syntax starting at v3.23 ([production release Jan, 2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)).  But the docs in the URL are for 4.1, which wasn't released until 2004.

SQL Server didn't have TOP until SQL Server 2000, [shipping in late 2000](http://www.microsoft.com/Presspass/press/2000/aug00/sqlserverpr.mspx).

Oracle has had [ROWNUM since Oracle 6](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/), released in ***1988***.  Scarier still, is that it can perform better in cases than ROW_NUMBER!

Comment: 22 years ago? Wow... talk about fast!

Comment: LIMIT/OFFSET was added in PostgreSQL 6.5, and is fully documented there. You are linking to 6.3 documentation... (FWIW, 6.5 was released in June 1999, but that was still after MySQL added LIMIT)

Answer (score 4):

MySQL copied it from mSQL, which Rasmus Lerdorf lays claim to implementing:
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail3298.html

That's not to say mSQL was the first, but it looks like earliest of those mentioned so far.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Rdb (originally a DEC Corporation product, now available from Oracle) had LIMIT TO n ROWS back in 1991.

Share and enjoy.